# "overflow-x: auto" not working as it should

Tags: html, css

I am trying with `overflow-x: auto`, but it is not working as it should. Where no scroll bar should be visible, it is showing horizontal scrollbar.

Vertical scrollbar(`overflow-y`) is working perfectly as desired, but horizontal scrollbar(`overflow-x`) is not working properly. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2p6yaovk/) link.

Comment: Hi your overflow-x: auto look fine : create scroll because body width = 1000px

Comment: Hi @ALWAN, yeah i knew that now. Any way to achieve this still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some minor changes required in your classes to get it work as you expected.

```
.container_row
{
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#name_label 
{
    list-style: disc inside;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    display: list-item;
    width: 50%;
}
#name_text
{
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline;
}
```

**Updated**

Check this [**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2p6yaovk/9/)

Comment: Yeah, It removed un-necessary horizontal scrollbar, but it moved content to new line.

Comment: hi @Hitesh, it worked but with one little issue. As you see, in the original jsfiddle, there is a fixed space between contents of id `name_label` and `name_text`. But in your jsfiddle, it is not there. I don't want to lose that. I need a fixed space. How can we achieve that?

Comment: best way to do that is to add padding-left: 10px; check the demo again.

Comment: yeah, it added padding, but it is not as it was previously. If you looked that again, you'll see that difference in your fiddle and mine.

Comment: hi, I've made changes again. Here's what you need i guess https://jsfiddle.net/2p6yaovk/9/ . you can remove padding if you want!

Comment: yeah, that's what I wanted. Kindly update your above answer to your newer changes, so, i could accept it. Thanks buddy.

Comment: Give me a minute.

Comment: Sounds great. Good luck bro!

Comment: Thanks once again @Hitesh. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

You're making your `#container1` larger than 100%. Change it to the following:

```
#container1 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope, it didn't wok.